# Unpack classes from a list into a module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm defining a few classes dynamically using `type()` and placing them in a list as I do so. I would, however, like to make the classes available from the module. That, for example, I can call `from factories import PersonFactory` if my module is `factories.py` and a dynamic class I create is `PersonFactory`.

This is a portion of the code in `factories.py`:

```
factories = []

for name, obj in models:
    factory_name = name + 'Factory' # e.g. PersonFactory
    attrs = assemble_factory_attrs(obj, factory_name)
    f = type(factory_name, (object,), attrs)
    factories.append(f)

# I wanted to "release" the classes into the module definition through `*factories`
# but I get this syntax error: "SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target"
*factories
```

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-a-while-loop

Comment: python treats `*factories` as an assignment; you can use `exec('%s = type(factory_name, (object,), attrs)' % factory_name)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them to the modules `globals()` -- it will look something like this:

```
factories = []
module = globals()

for name, obj in models:
    factory_name = name + 'Factory' # e.g. PersonFactory
    attrs = assemble_factory_attrs(obj, factory_name)
    f = type(factory_name, (object,), attrs)
    module[factory_name] = f
    factories.append(f)
```

Now they are both at the module (global) scope, and in the list `factories`.